# Why does the login_required decorator return a 302 status code?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a view that allows to add tags dynamically with an ajax request. It looks like this:

```
@require_POST
@login_required
def addtag(request):
   """
   a view to create a new tag in the tag database
   """
   some logic here
```

This is what my url.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^addtag/$',addtag, name='addtag'),
                      )
```

And my test is doing that:

```
def test_addtag(self):
    url='^addtag/$'

    response = self.client.post(url,{'addtag':'"new tag"'})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,401)
```

I expected the returned status code to be a 401, since the testclient is not logged in. So the first decorator, checking if the request is a post is being passed happily. Then i expected the login_required decorator to return a 401, but it didn't:

```
AssertionError: 302 != 401
```

First i thought the login_required decorator would be redirecting to some login page. Checked that, i do not have a `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` specified. So what is login_required doing in this case?

Comment: Did you check the response Location header ?

Comment: Great idea! Could bang my head against some wall... LOCATION was: `http://testserver/accounts/login/?next=/addtag/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@login_required` redirects to the login page if the user is not logged in -- hence the view returns 302 in such a case. (If you did not set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` it uses a default value.)

Comment: Thank you. And the default value can be seen in the comment to the question ;)

Comment: Please, can you explain why django uses 302 + Location instead of 401 + Location header ? I don't remember anything in the RFC that prevents from using 401 + Location.

Comment: @jpic: 401 is generally used in conjunction with HTTP access authorization.

Comment: @jpic From RFC2616 re: using 401: "The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource." The description doesn't indicate that it's appropriate to include a `Location` header for 401 responses.